Problemas con entity framework core
Al querer generar el modelo, partiendo desde la base de datos con el comando:

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=sql.bsite.net\MSSQL2016;Database=XXXX593_;User Id= XXXX593_;Password=pepe;" TrustServerCertificate=True  Microsoft.EntyFrameworkCore.SqlServer   --output-dir .\Data\BankModels --context-dir .\Data

me aparece el siguiente error:

Unrecognized command or argument 'Microsoft.EntyFrameworkCore.SqlServer'

Ya agregué las dos referencias al proyecto:

Microsoft.EntyFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntyFrameworkCore.Desing

, estoy trabajando con la versión 7, agregué también .tools pero me sigue ando el error, me pasa en dos maquinas distintas.

En tu comando pones Microsoft.EntyFramework y debería ser Microsoft.EntityFramework
